# PDF data is not being returned in a DocuSign webhook

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

I have created a webhook in the DocuSign sandbox environment.  In the Docusign Sandbox Admin, when configuring a connect web hook, I checked to include Document PDFs.  In my webhook, I am expecting to see a  node after the  end node.  I do not see it.  Am I doing anything wrong, or is this an issue with just the sandbox environment?  I have not tried it in production.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Remember to upvote all useful answers and check (accelt) the best answer to your questions

Comment: I tried but it is not letting me make the up vote public due to my low repuation

Comment: Try "checking" my answer. StackOverflow should allow that.

Comment: Thanks... that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each document PDF is included in a `PDFBytes` node. See the structure below.

I suggest using the [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) service to see exactly what is being sent to your listener.

If the documents aren't being included then the Connect (webhook) configuration is not set.

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
<DocumentPDFs>
    <DocumentPDF>
        <Name>NDA.pdf</Name>
        <PDFBytes>JVBERi0xLjQKJfv8/f4KNCAwIG9iago8PAov etc etc
```

Comment: I have not heard of this requestb.in service.  This is awesome! I saw that the PDF was indeed in the XML but was not being shown in the DocuSign logs.  Being that my test server was behind a firewall, I was posting to another server, and capturing the xml from the log to simulate a request in development.  This helped a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: Update... I am able to pull the PDF Byte Data out and write it to the file, but now it is saying that the new file is not a valid PDF.  Have you run into this?

Comment: You need to base64 decode the bytes.  Then you will have a regular pdf file.

Comment: file_put_contents($fullreposname, base64_decode ( (string)$pdf->PDFBytes ));